# C# apidoc typed viewer

Tags: c#, api, types, documentation

I am looking for a C# tool or Visual Studio Extension to visualize the typed api of all the library I use (because there is not type in the msdn doc, and some library have no apidoc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by typed api ? You can use the Object browser in Visual Studio if you want to look into the signatures of the dll you are referencing. 
Or if you want to generate documentation for a library you can use tools like [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx)

Comment: I want to see the whole api of a library with parameters types and return type

Comment: Can you give a definition of what "a whole api of a library is" ? As said, you can see the definition of a public method in a library (with all the input parameter and return types) by using the Object browser in Visual Studio. An alternative can be using Reflector.

Comment: A page with all the methods of a class, like in msdn but in better. I want the listing of the methods with types (parameter and return).

Comment: The Object Browser window in Visual Studio does it !! And if you want to produce documentation, like MSDN you can use GhostDoc or any other tool for generating documentation.

Comment: Thanks, it's almost what I want, it just miss the return type in the list.